# Directional differentiable + Lipschitz implies Hadamard and sequential continuity, applied to the function $\max(0,x)$

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, lipschitz-functions

We know the following: if $f \colon X \to Y$ is directionally differentiable and Lipschitz continuous then it is Hadamard differentiable. We also know that the Hadamard derivative is continuous wrt the direction (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3964996/302620)).

What I don't understand is the function $f(x) = \max(0,x)$ satisfies these conditions yet the derivative at $0$ is not continuous. We have
$$f'(0)(d) = \begin{cases}
1 &: d > 0\\
0 &: d <= 0
\end{cases}
$$
which is not continuous in $d$ (take $d_n = (-1)^n/n$ for example). What am I missing?

Here I use the following definitions:

$f$ is directionally differentiable at $x$ in direction $h$ if there is a function $f'(x)\colon X\rightarrow Y$ such that
\begin{align}
\lim_{t\rightarrow0+}\frac{f(x+th)-f(x)}{t}-f'(x)(h)=0
\end{align}

$f$ is Hadamard differentiable at $x$ in direction $h$ if there is a function $f'(x):X\rightarrow Y$ such that for any $h_t\xrightarrow{t\rightarrow0+}h$
\begin{align}
\lim_{t\rightarrow0+}\frac{f(x+th_t)-f(x)}{t}-f'(x)(h)=0
\end{align}

Comment: the directional derivative is equal to $f'(0;d) = \max(0,d)$, it has to scale with $d$.

Comment: Oops my bad thanks..